# Why does the weekly torah pirtion need to be read from a Torah scroll?

Tags: torah-service

Couldn't a regular Artscroll Chumash suffice? It would certainly make things easier for the Baal Kore.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dispute between the Rambam (Teshuvas Harambam 294) and the Rashba (Kalbo 20 in the name of the Rashba) as to whether one may use a Chumash for Kriyas HaTorah. The Rambam rules that one may use a Chumash and make a Bracha on Kriyas HaTorah done in a Chumash. However the Shulchan Aruch says that we follow the ruling of the Rashba that one may not make a Bracha on Kriyas HaTorah done in a Chumash and therefore we read from a actual Sefer Torah. [Please see this link for more on this subject.](http://www.etzion.org.il/dk/5771/1232maamar2.html)

Comment: You think an artscroll chumash is a pasul sefer Torah??